# Guardar relación has many en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, imagen, fileupload, relaciones

Una pregunta, cree una tabla nueva para guardar varias imágenes correspondientes a una propiedad.

El modelo lo hice de la siguiente manera:

**Modelo Propiedad**

```
public function imagenesPropiedades()
{
    return $this->hasMany(imgPropiedades::class);
}
```

**Modelo Imagenes Propiedades**

```
protected $table = 'img_propiedades';
protected $fillable = [
    'url', 'property_id'
];

public function properties(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Property::class);
}
```

Quiero guardar de forma relacionada las imagenes en la tabla img_propiedades

```
foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
         $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

         $properties = Property::create([
           $properties->imagenesPropiedades()->save($imgUrl)
         ]);
    }
```

El foreach así **no guarda todas las imágenes en el **store**** y además recibo el siguiente error: **Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save()**

¿Como es la forma correcta de guardar la relación? hay alguna forma de guardar este tipo de relación como cuando es muchos a muchos?

Ejemplo:

```
$properties->imagenesPropiedades()->attach($this->imagenes)
```

**EDICION**

De esta manera funciona perfecto... y por cierto desde ya muchas gracias @L.Flor

```
 $this->propiedadId = Property::where('user_id', $this->usuarioId)->pluck('id')->first();
    // Guardamos las imagenes
    foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
         $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

         $img = imgPropiedades::create([
           'url' => $imgUrl,
           'property_id' => $this->propiedadId
         ]);
    }
```

Quisiera evitar esta forma, si alguien conoce como se puede hacer directamente con la relación estaría muy agradecido, me gusta la idea de realizar algo así, pero no se si puede.

$properties->imagenesPropiedades()->attach($this->imagenes)

¿Algo así no se puede hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes una nueva tabla, entonces, debes crear tantos registros como imágenes haya dentro de ese `foreach`:

Previamente, debes haber creado tu Propiedad, para que le pases el id a cada registro de imágenes:

```
$property = Property::create([
     ...
    'user_id' => $this->usuarioId,
     ...
    
]);

foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
     $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');

     $properties = imgPropiedades::create([
       'url' => $imgUrl,
       'property_id' => $property->id
     ]);
}
```

---

Por otro lado, puedes utilizar [`createMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)

```
$paths = array();

foreach ($this->imagenes as $pathGaleria) {
     $imgUrl = $pathGaleria->store('imagenesPropiedades');
     
     $paths[] = array('url'=> $imgUrl);
}

$porperty->imagenesPropiedades()->createMany($paths);
```

Comment: Hola, si comprendo lo que me indicas. El tema es que las imágenes corresponde a una propiedad que está en proceso de creación por eso buscaba ver si era posible realizar la creación a través de la relación.

Comment: Podría crear la propiedad primero y obtener el id en el mismo create, para usar después en img_propiedades pero me parece que a futuro me puede generar un problema, algo así: $this->propiedadId = User::where('email', $this->email)->pluck('id')->first(); supongo que simultaneas creaciones acá podría ser un lío.